# CasperJS click not working properly with multiple submit buttons

Tags: casperjs

I have a form with 3 save buttons with ids 'save', 'save_new' & 'save_copy'. My server code performs different actions after saving depending on the presence of one of these fields in the http request block. When I use the browser and click on save for example the save parameter appears in the request object. When I use CasperJS click the save parameter is not present in the request block, so my code just performs the default action which is not the correct result.

```
casper.test.begin('Routine sample test', function suite (test) {
    casper.start();
    casper.setHttpAuth('<login>', '<pw>');
    casper.thenOpen('http://localhost/<sitename>/sample/routine/edit/0', function eval() {
        test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Routine Sample" );
        this.fill('form#routine_form', {
            <fill parameters>
        }, false);
        this.click("#save_new");                                 
    });
    casper.then(function() {
        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl()); 
        test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Routine Sample" );
        var sample_id = this.fetchText('[name="sample_id"]');
        test.assertEval( function(sample_id) { return sample_id > 0 }, "Sample created" );
    });
    casper.run(function() {test.done();});
});
```

The final test fails because the server has not returned the page I was expecting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like you're using a feature that is not supported by PhantomJS. Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: as matter of interest what happens if you change `casper.then(function() {`  to `casper.waitForText('SOME TEXT ON SECOND PAGE', function() {`

Comment: PhantomJS 2.1.1, CasperJS 1.1.0
The submit is working but the submit button value is not being sent to the back to the server so my server code does not know which button is being clicked.